# WSMan Works, WinRM Running, PSSession Doesn't Resolve Anything Just Hangs

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have three devices on the same network on the same domain.

- Server1
- Server2
- Workstation1

All devices have PSRemoting enabled. Server1 can `Enter-PSSession` on Server 2. Server2 can `Enter-PSSession` on Server 1. But Workstation1 cannot `Enter-PSSession` onto either Server1 or Server2.

What happens when I try to `Enter-PSSession` FROM Workstation1 is nothing. Literally nothing. No error logs, no error messages. The shell just hangs. Or, when using `New-PSSession` in ISE, ISE doesn't freeze, but it just hangs on completing a `Invoke-Command` basic script.

Here's what I've tried to do to fix Workstation1

- I noticed the local administrator account was disabled and did not have a password set. This created some issues for my Domain Admin account. So I set the Administrator account password, enabled it, and restarted. This fixed a lot of problems. But nothing with PSSession.
- I set Server1 and Workstation1 as trusted hosts using the the following command `winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="ComputerName"}'`. No errors are thrown, both are trusted. Still nothing.
- I test WinRM between Server1 and Workstation1 with the following command `test-wsman -ComputerName Server1` the test returns with successful results. No errors are returned.
- I set the IdleTimeout for WinRM to 18 seconds using the following command: `winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{IdleTimeout="18000"}'` still nothing

Nothing worked. One thing I noticed was that Server1 and Server2 are running Powershell4.0 Build 6.3, and Workstation1 is running Powershell5.1.1629, Build 10.0. I can't find any documentation on why this would matter, but it's literally all I can consider at this point.

Comment: Hi Fishcakes, I recommend you post this on [sf], as it's more aboout server administration than programming and is likely to get better responses there.

Comment: I'll do that, thank you!